# Replace foreign key with name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

So basically, I'm making a website that gets some info and shows it.

Currently I have it showing everything I want, except I'm using an ID instead of a name. The ID of a user, and I want to replace the ID with the actual name.

If you look here

```
     @foreach(var m in Model.Commits)
     {
        if(m.ProjectName == Model.SelectedProject)
        {
        <tr>
           <th>@m.UserID</th>
           <th>@m.Date</th>
           <th>@m.Message</th>
           <th>@m.BranchName</th>
           <th>@m.Host</th>
           <th>@m.RepositoryPath</th>
        </tr>  
        }
     }
```

I believe it may be something I have to do inside my controller, but I'm new to MVC and these mo' fo'in' controllers are driving me insane.

Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the 'name' property is in the 'Commits' object then you should be able to display it with no problems at all.

However, I suspect it may not be that straight-forward. The M in MVC stands for Model, and in the example you've provided the Commits class is the model for your view. Your controller should be calling something to populate/hydrate this 'Commits' model. Have a look at that.

If you are not used to MVC it takes a while to get used to things not all being together. Soon though it'll make sense. The problem then of course is when you go back to code that wasn't written in MVC and start shuddering.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think Commits is domain model not viewmodel. You need create viewmodel. For example

```
public class CommitViewModel
{
  public DateTime Date{get;set;}
  public String Message{get;set;}
  //other properties
  public string UserName {get;set;}
}
```

In controller initialize viewmodel by domain model and pass to view.

Comment: Ahh! I think I get what you mean. I'll need to shift some stuff about, but I'll give it a go.